# Better practice of using static libraries in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, shared-libraries, system, static-libraries

I am new to unix.
This is the first time I am trying work with an external library(Ogre3D) on a Mac. I do not want to dump all of the .lylib files in into the /usr/lib directory since I might want to delete these files once I do not need them and it's hard to differentiate them form other library files. When I create a new folder named Ogre in the /usr/lib/ directory to host my Ogre library files it seems I cannot access these files when compiling files using -l flags to specify the location. So I am wondering if it's necessary to put all the files in the /usr/lib/ rather than putting them into a folder inside the /usr/lib/?

And I wondering that if it is possible to put the includes folder directly into /usr/includes/ so I can access the header files? Or I have to put all the headers in the /usr/includes/?

Comment: I believe that you should rather avoid using static libraries, and only use shared libraries. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/

Comment: And your question mentions a Mac but is tagged Linux... why??? (are you running Linux on a Mac laptop?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am wondering if it's necessary to put all the files in the /usr/lib/ rather than putting them into a folder inside the /usr/lib/?

No. There's the `-L<dir>` linker flag which makes the compiler search `dir` along with the standard library paths.

> And I wondering that if it is possible to put the includes folder directly into /usr/includes/ so I can access the header files?

Even more choices here. Either put them in `/usr/include/foo` and then

```
#include <foo/foo.h>
```

(preferred) or put them in `/usr/include/foo`, use the `-I/usr/include/foo` compiler flag, and write

```
#include <foo.h>
```